# Why does this order of a Python if statement matter?

Tags: python

This is my code for a Leetcode problem, and I'm wondering why one if statement works but the other does not.

```
def validWordSquare(words):
    for row in range(len(words)):
        for column in range(len(words[row])):
            # if row >= len(words[column]) or column >= len(words) or words[row][column] != words[column][row]:  # doesn't work
            if column >= len(words) or row >= len(words[column]) or words[row][column] != words[column][row]:  # works
                return False

    return True

words = ["abc","b"]
print(validWordSquare(words))
```

Comment: If `column` is out of range, then `len(words[column])` is not a valid expression - checking `column` as the second thing you do is too late.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation may help. Python does this.

Comment: [HERE](https://eng.libretexts.org/Courses/Delta_College/Introduction_to_Programming_Concepts_-_Python/03%3A_Conditional_Execution/3.08%3A_Short-Circuit_Evaluation_of_Logical_Expressions) is a good explanation this concept looking specifically at Python

Answer (score 2):

```
def validWordSquare(words):
    for row in range(len(words)):
        for column in range(len(words[row])):
            print(f'{row=} {column=}')
            if row >= len(words[column]) or column >= len(words) or words[row][column] != words[column][row]:  # doesn't work
            # if column >= len(words) or row >= len(words[column]) or words[row][column] != words[column][row]:  # works
                return False

    return True

words = ["abc","b"]
print(validWordSquare(words))
```

Testing output
Notice column = 2 is out of range in the code.

```
row=0 column=0
row=0 column=1
row=0 column=2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ctynd\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm2021.3\scratches\scratch.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(validWordSquare(words))
  File "C:\Users\ctynd\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm2021.3\scratches\scratch.py", line 5, in validWordSquare
    if row >= len(words[column]) or column >= len(words) or words[row][column] != words[column][row]:  # doesn't work
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Evaluating `column >= len(words)` first prevents `row >= len(words[column])` from being evaluated if `column` is out of range for that expression.  This is called [short-circuit evaluation](https://eng.libretexts.org/Courses/Delta_College/Introduction_to_Programming_Concepts_-_Python/03%3A_Conditional_Execution/3.08%3A_Short-Circuit_Evaluation_of_Logical_Expressions).